# Android: Custom MenuItem for onNavigationItemSelected?

Tags: android, menuitem, navigation-drawer

I'm developing an app using the official android `NavigationDrawer`, i have created my own custom `MenuItem` because the default MenuItem allows you to assign one `string` to it through `menuItem.setTitle()`, but i want to add another string too. So i created this custom CatMenuItem.java:

[image: 1st screenshot]

As you can see it implements the `MenuItem` and i added a string named `catId` and a setter and a getter for this string.

Now in the `onNavigationItemSelected` in the `MainActivity` when i put CatMenuItem instead of the MenuItem as parameter i get an error saying `Method does not override method from its superclass`:

[image: 2nd screenshot]

I have tried everything and searched so many articles, nothing works, keep in mind that i don't want to change the menu to a `ListView`, i want the menu as it is.

**What i want is:** get the the string `catId` from the selected MenuItem.

Any help is very appreciated.

**EDIT** setting the `catId`:
In the MainActivity i have made a method called `getContents` to get contents from a url (JSON) to assign the values to the menu, you can see in the picture below how i assigned the values to catId:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try keeping the parameter the same for `onNavigationItemSelected()` instead, and just cast the parameter like so:

```
@Override
public void onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    CatMenuItem catMenuItem = (CatMenuItem) menuItem;
}
```

Comment: I tries that as well, didn't work; i got this error `android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl cannot be cast to com.my.app.CatMenuItem`

Answer (score 0):

Activity class doesn't hold the method `onNavigationItemSelected`.You have to implement [NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener.html) in your MainActivity in order to override it.

Comment: It's implemented already, it works fine when the parameter is `MenuItem item` but it doesn't work when i change the parameter to `CatMenuItem item`

Comment: That would change the method param type which violates the method signature. Check the crymson's answer.

Comment: Didn't work too because of this: `android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl cannot be cast to com.my.app.CatMenuItem`